# Firebase Admin when I add a user email is anonymous

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

IM using the new firebase admin SDK for node js and I created an api where I can add users. Everything is working fine but when I see a new user in my firebase dashboard I find Anonymous.

Comment: Quick educated guess below. But it would be easier to help if you share the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a custom authentication token with Firebase Admin SDK, those users are not shown in the Firebase Authentication console.

Comment: It's not a custom token but a normal Register request with the Admin SDK

Comment: OK. In that case: please share the minimal code that is needed to reproduce the issue.