# Firebase-Admin user created with email appears anonymous

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm using the admin sdk with a minimal (name/email/password) form. A user created with email provided still appears anonymous in the console.

[image: firebase console image]

My code: (NodeJs)

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const secret = require('./../credentials/server');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(secret),
  databaseURL: 'url',
});
module.exports = (user) => {
  admin.auth().createUser({
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password,
    displayName: user.name,
  })
    .then((userRecord) => {
      // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
      console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.uid);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
    });
};
```

I also found this question on stackoverflow but the answer didn't seem to solve the issue:
[Firebase Admin when I add a user email is anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42000449/firebase-admin-when-i-add-a-user-email-is-anonymous)

Comment: I was able to create a user with a visible email using your code. The only difference was instead of using the `user` object, I hard-coded the values for the user. Try logging `user.email` and `user.displayName` to see if they have values.

Comment: @JenPerson You are right, I had forgotten to correctly populate the req.body object which by default is undefined in Express. Used body-parser.

Thanks a lot!